# Pandas DataFrame with index to JSON

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I want to output a simple DataFrame to JSON, but the following complains that `DataFrame index must be unique for orient=` no matter what I put in the orient argument.

```
pd.DataFrame({'Client': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}) \
             .set_index('Client') \
             .to_json()
```

Desired output:

```
[{'Client': 1, 'Name': ['A', 'B']},
 {'Client': 2, 'Name': ['C', 'D']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: `groupby` `Client`, aggregating `Name` to a list, then convert to dict and make a list of the values of the dict which you then convert to JSON:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Client': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
out = json.dumps(
    list(df
        .groupby('Client', as_index=False)
        .agg(list)
        .to_dict(orient='index')
        .values()
    )
)
```

Output:

```
'[{"Client": 1, "Name": ["A", "B"]}, {"Client": 2, "Name": ["C", "D"]}]'
```